# C# Property in class with not defined type

Tags: c#

I want to create some class in C# (let's say it class Attribute)

```
public class Attribute
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The entity of this class will have ID, Name and Value properties.

The main problem is that I want to save in property Value different types of data: String, int, double, DateTime and so on.

What is the best way to make solutions like this?

Comment: try `dynamic` data type, or simply use `object` and cast every time you need.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I think it will good for me

Comment: @AlexZhulin: dou you plan to store these entities in relational database?

Comment: Yes, I do. Will I have some difficulties with this implementation?

Comment: @AlexZhulin: of course, you will. It depends on what approach are you going to use to store them: raw ADO .NET, data sets, ORM (like Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc...). I think, better edit the question and add database-specific info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a generic Type?

```
public class Attribute<T>
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Edited:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var attribute = new Attribute<int>(){ ID = 1, Name = "TheName", Value = 46 };
}
```

Comment: Could you give me example how to use this generic type with entity of this type. Say I want to create entity with int value.

Thanks

Comment: Edited ... like this?

Comment: THis iwll not work - and it is a nonsensible request becase at the end the database also does not support that.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: although OP accepted this as an answer, it seems to me, that ultimately these entites should be stored in database. Hence, the answer should contain store specific, like TomTom hints.

Comment: Where did you read anything that suggest it should be stored to a database?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: call it intuition. :) Also, read OP comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

Usuage will be like this

```
    int result =10;
    Attribute<int> objAttribute = new Attribute<int>();
    objAttribute.value = result;

    string strResult ="Sucess";
    Attribute<string> objAttribute1 = new Attribute<string>();
    objAttribute1.value = strResult ;
```